# How can I get a list of files needed by a Webpack entry?

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack setup where every entry point is an app. In this setup, I'd like to create a serviceworker per app which pre-caches every file needed by that app. Is this possible? I was told that Stats might help me, which works fine for the js bundles & chunks, and even the CSS I extract (via ExtractTextWebpackPlugin), but I'm having trouble connecting the files found in CSS files (such as font files) back to an entry point.

Here's my Stats file:
https://gist.github.com/plestik/8190280a965ef9e429cc

How do I connect the font files (.eot etc) back to my apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working for my use case by hooking into [`module-asset`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html#module-asset). At that point, you have a `Compilation` object with the entry point that's currently being processed. [Here's how I'm using it](https://bitbucket.org/dgieselaar/zaaksysteem/src/463cea0780ee5bfe54714d3540353eabf862d951/client/ServiceWorkerCachePlugin.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).